# How do I get data from XML into excel using VBA?

Tags: xml, vba, excel

I am a high school student doing a science research project. I am not experienced at programming in excel though i do have a good understanding of general programming and logic. This is my first post.

I have done a thorough google search but I can't seem to find what i'm looking for. 
Here I need to simply grab elevation data from this webservice: hhttp://ned.usgs.gov/epqs/
All I need to know is how to have excel grab the inner text from the xml such as this: http://ned.usgs.gov/epqs/pqs.php?x=-73.06&y=40.8725&units=Feet&output=xml

Here is my code so far:

```
    Sub elevgrabwebserv()

Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
Dim elev As String
Dim lat As String
Dim longt As String
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Both")

IE.Visible = False

lr = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 3 To lr
If sht.Cells(i, 7) > 0 And IsEmpty(sht.Cells(i, 14)) Then

lat = sht.Cells(i, 7)
longt = sht.Cells(i, 8)

IE.navigate "http://ned.usgs.gov/epqs/pqs.php?x=" & longt & "&y=" & lat & "&units=Feet&output=xml"

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Set Doc = IE.document

'here below is the problem
elev = Doc.getElementsByName("elevation").innerText

'from here parse the inner text to fit my needs



End If
Next i

End Sub
```

[Here is the sample data that I need to get. As you can see, I need to run this web service many times, hence my for loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cC32O.png)

Thank you so much in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a VBA project reference to the library "Microsoft VML v6.0":

```
Sub Tester()
    Debug.Print Elevation(-73.06, 40.8725)
End Sub


Function Elevation(x, y)
    Dim http As New XMLHTTP60
    Dim doc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    http.Open "GET", "http://ned.usgs.gov/epqs/pqs.php?x=" & x & _
                     "&y=" & y & "&units=Feet&output=xml"
    http.send
    doc.LoadXML http.responseText
    Elevation = doc.getElementsByTagName("Elevation")(0).nodeTypedValue
End Function
```